# How do I give a two dimensional array 2nd slot "unlimited space"? JAVA

Tags: java

If I want to make an array that has different sizes for each inner array, how do I declare it?
int[][] arr = new int [X][]; (The x being a certain number) gives me null when I try to use it and put things in the array.

However, I want different sizes for each inner array, depending on what I'm trying to input into it. What do I do? Java BTW.

For the code:

```
    int[][] arr3 = new int [arr1.length+arr2.length][];
    for(int i = 0; i<arr1.length; i = i + 1)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<arr1[i].length; j = j + 1)
        {
            arr3[i][j] = arr1[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i2 = 0; i2< arr2.length; i2 = i2 + 1)
    {
        for (int j2 = 0; j2<arr2[i2].length; j2 = j2 + 1)
        {
            arr3[i2+arr1.length][j2] = arr2[i2][j2];
        }
    }
    return arr3;
}
```

I want to put arr1 inner arrays and arr2 inner arrays into arr3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```java
int [][] y = new int[10][];
```

You then have to assign a regular array to the area you want to use.

```java
y[0] = new int[20];
y[1] = new int[12];
```

and so forth.

Those are typically referred to as ragged arrays.